# how to create an anchor point

Tags: html, css, anchor

I have tried to create an anchor point using:

```
<a href="index-xxx.html#reference-name"> and

<a name="reference-name">
```

The problem is I have a floating margin on the top and the anchor point goes to the top of the page hiding the top of the text.

Is there an easy way to add a relative spacing to the top margin using HTML?

I'm new to this and using a template that I found online. I have since found that it would have been easier to start from fresh instead of using the template but I am too far down the line now, and I don't really understand how to change the CSS to do this. Is there an easier answer?

Many thanks in advance to someone that has been searching for hours for the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure there's enough code here to provide a meaningful answer. Can you provide a bit more code (HTML and CSS) for "i have a floating margin on the top and the anchor point goes to the top of the page hiding the top of the text"?

Comment: sorry im that new i wouldnt know what to send... still learning

Comment: basically i have a header menu on each page of the site that is about an inch thick, ive created an anchor point that seems to work fine but when the link takes me to the anchor point it takes the link to the very top of the page and i need the link to be an inch down the page

Comment: sorry so that is not hidden by the menu

Comment: is there a way to put something by the anchor point that makes the text 200px down the page for exapmle

Comment: Ah, so you're positioning the menu (CSS 'position')? I'd have to see the CSS, but a hack would be to put some top margin on the text, say ~200px+.

Comment: the only problem is the text im linking to is in a full page of text and im linking halfway down the page, if i insert a text margin it leaves a blank space in the page when i look at it as a whole

Comment: whats the best way to show you the css, by the way many thanks for your help

Comment: Depending upon how comfortable you are with sharing it, I'd say post the HTML and CSS page to a temporary location on your server, and link to it from here. If that's not an option, update your question with the CSS and HTML. Try to limit what you post to only the relevant content. We'll let you know if we need more :)

Comment: i dont have a server yet still finishing the website first... very novice

Comment: what part of the css do you need

Comment: CSS on the body, the menu, and if you're styling the anchor point. I just re-read your post and forgot you're using a template. Is that something you can update your post to link to (assuming it's not for-pay)?

Comment: #logo {
 position: absolute;
 font-size:70px;
 top: 0;
 left: 13px;
 line-height:101px;
 letter-spacing:-2px;
}
#logo a{text-decoration:none; color:#fff}
#logo a span{color:#ffe400}
#logo2 {
 position: absolute;
 font-size:50px;
 top: 0;
 left: 230px;
 line-height:115px;
 letter-spacing:-2px;
}

Comment: #logo2 a{text-decoration:none; color:#fff}
#logo2 a span{color:#ffe400}
nav{position:absolute; right:0; text-transform:uppercase; border-top:3px solid #ffe400; height:98px; font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:bold; font-size:1.3em}
 nav li{float:left}
 nav a{color:#fff; text-decoration:none; line-height:98px; padding:0 13px; display:inline-block}
 nav .active a, nav a:hover{background:#252525}

Comment: it was a pay template and is not there any more

Comment: (FYI, if you edit your question and paste in the code, with three spaces before each line, you'll get nice color coding.) Can you update your question with the HTML from your body to the anchor? You can remove all the text from the logo and logo2 divs.

Comment: starting to get confused... doesnt take much im afraid ill try

Comment: I've posted an answer. Let's work from that, if it doesn't clear up the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I've updated based upon the code supplied.

Basically we've got something to the effect of this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
    #main {
        min-width: 980px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-size: 0.75em;
        padding:101px 0 37px 0;
    }
    header {
        height:101px;
        background:url(../images/footer_tail.jpg) left top repeat #0d0d0d;
        position:fixed;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        width:100%;
        z-index:100;
    }
    footer {
        overflow: hidden;
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
        width:100%/*; height:37px*/;
        background:url(../images/footer_tail.jpg) left top repeat #0d0d0d;
        color:#9d9d9d;
        text-transform:uppercase
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <header>...</header>
    <section id="content">... with <a name="blah">anchor</a> a couple paragraphs down the page</section>
    <footer>...</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As written the anchors links are buried under the top navigation. It seems the only solid fix is to use 'CSS frames' to get the content to display correctly, which requires the following CSS tweaks:

```
#main 
{
    padding:0 0 37px 0;
}
section#content
{
    position:fixed;
    top:101px;
    width:100%;
    bottom:37px;
    overflow:auto;
}
footer 
{
    position:fixed;
    height:37px;
}
```

So I've removed the top padding from #main.

Then I made the content and footer fixed position. Because of this the content has to be moved down 101px, hence the top.

I then had to give the footer a height, and then put that same amount as a bottom on the content.

Overflow auto gives us scrollbars, and width of 100% puts those bars in a reasonable place.

Tested on IE 9, Chrome 10, Firefox 4, and Opera 11.

Edit 2: And unfortunately I can't find much online about this particular method. Eric Meyer talks about it in Smashing CSS. It doesn't look like any of the existing resources online test for how anchor links will work with the content, which is pretty unfortunate.

Comment: James, many thanks for your help it has been much appreciated, only problemn is i think this is a bit beyond my level at the moment as i dont really understand what to do - not your fault im just very new to this.

Comment: I'll defer to you, but based on your situation, if you want to shoot me an email at StrivingLife [at] gmail [dot] com with the CSS and HTML I can give this a look tonight after work. We can get that working and update the question/answer accordingly.

Comment: I had mentioned a possible JavaScript way, in case you want the scrollbar to be completely at the top. Looks like it was http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?t=26767, but fair warning that I haven't tried this myself.

Comment: No problem Matt :) Enjoy Stack Overflow!